# Windows Powershell AddType jar extension not supported

Tags: java, powershell

I'm attempting to use Windows Powershell to query a DB2 database using db2jcc.jar to connect.

$classpath is set to the Windows path of db2jcc.jar.

Add-Type -Path "$classpath"

fails with messsage:
Add-Type : Cannot add type. The ".JAR" extension is not supported.

So how do I use jdbc to connect to DB2 with Powershell?

Comment: Powershell doesn't support Java archives, so what you are trying to do will not work. Either use Java all the way, use ODBC, or [DB2 native .Net](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-warehouse?topic=programmatically-net) library.

Comment: Interesting. ChatGPT provided the solution to use Add-Type -P with a jar. It's not so smart after all. Thanks!